# Extraer información de diferentes nodos XML con el mismo PATH con PYTHON

Tags: python, xml

Estoy intentando extraer la información que contienen distintos nodos dentro de un mismo path:

La parte de XML que me esta dándo problemas es la siguente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que he utilizado para extraer el texto de dentro de estos nodos es el siguente:

```
for nodo in tree.find(/Body/.../RateEntryCollection/RateEntry)
print(nodo.text)
```

El problema es que con esta funcion solo puedo entraer información en el primer nodo "RateEntry".

Como puedo entrar dentro de los otros nodos que tienen el mismo Path?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿no deberías iterar más bien por los nodos dentro de /Body/.../RateEntryCollection/ ?

Comment: No me aparece ninguna información de esa forma...

Answer (score 2):

En este caso puedes jugar un poco con [XPATH](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) para conseguir lo que deseas.

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente XML:

```
<firstNode>
    <RateEntryCollection>
        <RateEntry Action ="MERGE">
            <anotherNode>
                Example1
            </anotherNode>
        </RateEntry>
        <RateEntry Action ="MERGE">
            <anotherNode>
                Example2
            </anotherNode>
        </RateEntry>
    </RateEntryCollection>
</firstNode>
```

Supongamos que queremos todas los elementos (para ello usamos `.//*` para obtener todo desde la raíz:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("example.xml")

root = tree.getroot()

for element in root.findall(".//*"):
    print(element)
```

Resultado:

```
<Element 'RateEntryCollection' at 0x7f67e2e26430>
<Element 'RateEntry' at 0x7f67e2e26480>
<Element 'anotherNode' at 0x7f67e2e264d0>
<Element 'RateEntry' at 0x7f67e2e26570>
<Element 'anotherNode' at 0x7f67e2e265c0>
```

En caso de necesitar los elementos `RateEntry`, sabiendo la estructura:

```
for rate_entry in root.findall(".//RateEntryCollection/*"):
    print(rate_entry)
```

Nos devuelve:

```
<Element 'RateEntry' at 0x7ff83708e520>
<Element 'RateEntry' at 0x7ff83708e610>
```

Si deseas solo el primero puedes jugar como un array:

```
for rate_entry in root.findall(".//RateEntryCollection/RateEntry[1]"):
    print(rate_entry)
```

Resultado:

```
<Element 'RateEntry' at 0x7f1b3b5e6570>
```

Si deseas el contenido del `tag` Action:

```
for rate_entry in root.findall(".//RateEntryCollection/RateEntry[1]"):
    print(rate_entry.get('Action'))
```

Resultado:

```
MERGE
```

P.D: Sino es lo que buscas, trata, por favor, de colocar un ejemplo válido para poder ayudarte mejor :)